# Sitecore DataProvider with multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore7, dataprovider

I have been reading several examples of Sitecore DataProvider implementation on single database and single table (using the config file parameters to specify particular table and columns trying to integrate with). Just wonder if it is possible to implement the dataprovider working on multiple tables instead of just one. Couldn't find any examples on this, just asking for any ideas or possibilities.

First problem I encounter when I try to deal with multiple tables is to override GetItemDefinition method. Since this method returns only one item definition and needs to know which particular table it will get the item information from. (This is specified in the config file if just dealing with one table). Basically I am looking for a way to switch (dynamically) between tables without changing the config file params every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a custom data provider then then implemetation is left entirely up to you. If you have been following some of the examples such, such as the [Northwind Dataprovider](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Northwind_Data_Provider.aspx) then as you state the implementation acts on a single database as specified in config. But you can specify whatever you need in the methods that you implement, and run logic to switch the `select` statement you call in the methods such as `GetItemDefinition()` and `GetItemFields()`. You can see in the Northwind exmaple that the SQL query is dynamically built:

```
StringBuilder sqlSelect = new StringBuilder();
sqlSelect.AppendFormat("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", nameField, table);
```

If you are building a read-only dataprovider then you might be able to make use of [SQL Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(v=sql.80).aspx), allowing you to write a query to combine the results from several tables using [`UNION` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx). As long as each record has a unique ID across tables (i.e. if you are using GUIDs as the ID) then this should work fine.